# Image Not Displaying On Page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I am working on MVC 5 ASP.net. When I am using razor syntax image is not showing on web page otherwise same hard coded value is working.

Here is the code.

```
    @{
       var path = "";
    }
    @foreach (Movy a in Model)
    {
            if (a.Image == null)
            {
                path = "~/Content/images/c3.jpg";
            }
            else
            {
                path = a.Image;
            }
        <img src="@path" />
    }
```

but when I replace @path to "~/Content/images/c3.jpg" in source of image it works.

Comment: What is output in the markup when you use `@path`?

Comment: I have checked the page source from browser... It is showing the same value i.e "~/Content/images/c3.jpg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to resolve the string in run time. Use `Url.Content`

`<img src="@Url.Content(path)" />`

Comment: Thanks buddy. It worked. I searched everywhere but didn't get this. Can you explain why it did not read @path ?

Comment: @UsamaSaleem when you hardcode the path like `"~/Content/images/c3.jpg"` it works because the runtime will resolve it .. But when you are setting it using `@path` the run time will just replace the value as a plain string but not resolve it.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
  <img src= "@Url.Content(path)" alt="Image" />
```